# Cleaning code with too much conditionals

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, anti-patterns

I've found this ugly piece of code from some time ago:

```
@FXML
private void buttSellAction(ActionEvent event){
    InfoTip infoTip = new InfoTip();
    if(comboPizza.getValue() != null){
        if(comboPizzaSize.getValue() != null){
            PizzaData selectedPizza = getPizzaData(comboPizza.getValue());
            PizzaSizeData selectedPizzaSize = getPizzaSizeData(comboPizzaSize.getValue());
            Date date = new Date();
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            if( selectedPizza != null ){                    
                if(groupDelivery.getSelectedToggle().equals(radioNo)){ // sale without delivery
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Confirm");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Total cost: " + String.format("%.2f", selectedPizza.getPrice() + selectedPizzaSize.getPrice()));
                    alert.setContentText("Proceed with sale?");

                    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
                    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                        insertSale(timestamp, currentUser.getLogin(), selectedPizza.getID(), 
                                   selectedPizzaSize.getSize(), false, selectedPizza.getPrice() + selectedPizzaSize.getPrice());

                        infoTip.getInfoTip().setId("greenInfoTip");
                        infoTip.showTip((Button)event.getSource(), "   Saved   ");
                    }
                }else{ //Sale with delivery
                    String adress = textFAdress.getText();
                    String clientName = textFClientName.getText();
                    String telephone = textFTelephone.getText();
                    String deliveryCost = textFCost.getText();

                    boolean isAdressOK = ((adress.length() < 51) && (adress.isEmpty() == false))? true: false;
                    boolean isClientNameOK = (clientName.length() < 36)? true: false;
                    boolean isTelephoneOK = ((telephone.length() < 21) && (telephone.isEmpty() == false))? true: false;
                    boolean isCostOK;
                    try{ Double.valueOf(deliveryCost); isCostOK = true; }
                    catch(NumberFormatException exception){ isCostOK = false; }

                    if(isAdressOK == true){
                        if(isClientNameOK == true){
                            if(isTelephoneOK == true){
                                if(isCostOK == true){
                                    double totalCost = selectedPizza.getPrice() + selectedPizzaSize.getPrice() + Double.valueOf(deliveryCost);
                                    //everything is okey
                                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                                    alert.setTitle("Confirm");
                                    alert.setHeaderText("Total cost: " + totalCost);
                                    alert.setContentText("Proceed with sale?");

                                    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
                                    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                                        int id = insertSale(timestamp, currentUser.getLogin(), selectedPizza.getID(), 
                                                selectedPizzaSize.getSize(), true, selectedPizza.getPrice() + selectedPizzaSize.getPrice());

                                        insertDelivery(id, adress, clientName, telephone, Double.valueOf(deliveryCost));

                                        infoTip.getInfoTip().setId("greenInfoTip");
                                        infoTip.showTip((Button)event.getSource(), "   Saved   ");
                                    } else {
                                        // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
                                    }
                                }else{ //cost not ok
                                    infoTip.showTip(textFCost, "keep right format e.g. 4.35");
                                }
                            }else{ //telephone not ok
                                infoTip.showTip(textFTelephone, "max 20 characters, not empty");
                            }
                        }else{ //client name not ok
                            infoTip.showTip(textFClientName, "max 35 characters");
                        }
                    }else{ //adress not ok
                        infoTip.showTip(textFAdress, "max 50 characters, not empty");
                    }
                }
            }else{ //couldnt found selected pizza in pizzaList(which should not be possible)
                ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("Error when searching for selected pizza", new Exception());
                exceptionDialog.showAndWait();
            }
        }else{ //pizza size not choosen
            infoTip.showTip(comboPizzaSize, "select pizza size");
        }
    }else{ //pizza not choosen
        infoTip.showTip(comboPizza, "select pizza");
    }
}
```

I know now it has few major flaws:

- method is doing too much and its too long,
- it has too many conditional statements so it is easy to get lost,
- unnecessary comments making code less readable.
- repeated code,
- possibly mixed levels of complexity.
- testing it would be horrible.
- something else??

How can I refactor it to make it clean and simple?

Comment: "Unnecessary comments"? Really?  This is hardly buried under explantory comment text.

Comment: they are usefull, but they are side-effects of complex code.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

I'd take a slightly different approach to the other answer. I'd separate the validation from the other logic in the method. This means that you don't have to read lots of if statements to see the core logic of the method and if you want to change the validation you only need to update one statement in one place. eg for the first section, add a private method:

```
private PizzaSizeData getAndVerifySelectedPizza() {
    if (comboPizza.getValue() == null) {
        infoTip.showTip(comboPizza, "select pizza");
        return null;
    }

    if (comboPizzaSize.getValue() == null) {
        infoTip.showTip(comboPizzaSize, "select pizza size");
        return null;
    }

    PizzaData selectedPizza = getPizzaData(comboPizza.getValue());
    if (selectedPizza == null) {
        ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("Error when searching for selected pizza", new Exception());
        exceptionDialog.showAndWait();
        return null;
    }

    return getPizzaSizeData(comboPizzaSize.getValue());
}
```

You could return optionals instead of null but this illustrates the mechanism.

And then call the new method:

```
private void buttSellAction(ActionEvent event){
    InfoTip infoTip = new InfoTip();

    PizzaSizeData selectedPizzaSize = getAndVerifySelectedPizza();
    if (selectedPizzaSize == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Carry on with the method....
```

Putting validation at the start of a method with an early return statement is a common pattern so the multiple returns aren't going to confuse anyone and they allow each validation rule to be written separately.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ladder if else` in your code. like this

```
if(isAdressOK == true && isClientNameOK == true && isTelephoneOK == true && isCostOK == true){
    double totalCost = selectedPizza.getPrice() + selectedPizzaSize.getPrice() + Double.valueOf(deliveryCost);
    //everything is okey
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirm");
    alert.setHeaderText("Total cost: " + totalCost);
    alert.setContentText("Proceed with sale?");
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
        int id = insertSale(timestamp, currentUser.getLogin(), selectedPizza.getID(), 
                selectedPizzaSize.getSize(), true, selectedPizza.getPrice() + selectedPizzaSize.getPrice());

        insertDelivery(id, adress, clientName, telephone, Double.valueOf(deliveryCost));

        infoTip.getInfoTip().setId("greenInfoTip");
        infoTip.showTip((Button)event.getSource(), "   Saved   ");
    } else {
        // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
    }
}else if(!isAdressOK == true){
    infoTip.showTip(textFAdress, "max 50 characters, not empty");
}else if(!isClientNameOK == true){
    infoTip.showTip(textFClientName, "max 35 characters");
}else if(!isTelephoneOK == true){
    infoTip.showTip(textFTelephone, "max 20 characters, not empty");
}else{ 
    infoTip.showTip(textFCost, "keep right format e.g. 4.35");
}
```

same for other if else condition.

Comment: Why `isXxxxOK == true` instead of simply `isXxxxOK`?

Comment: Since the adress is checked first, I'd use 'else if(!isAdressOK){
      infoTip.showTip(textFAdress, "max 50 characters, not empty"); 
      }else if(!isClientNameOK){
      infoTip.showTip(textFClientName, "max 35 characters"); 
      }else if(!isTelephoneOK){
      infoTip.showTip(textFTelephone, "max 20 characters, not empty"); 
      }else if(!isCostOK){
      infoTip.showTip(textFCost, "keep right format e.g. 4.35"); 
      }'